# detect a pattern in String using str_detect

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to detect if a string contains a specific pattern using `str_detect`. The pattern I have is a series of "...." - exact number of dots is unknown. I'm trying to use `str_detect` as below....

However, in this particular case, `str_detect` returns TRUE. Wondering where I am doing it wrong and if `str_detect` is the right function to use at all? Hoping someone here can help?

```
library(stringr)
dot_pat="\\.........................";
str="The primary.objective is of the study."
str_detect(str,dot_pat)
```

This returns TRUE. I'm expecting FALSE since the dots in `str` do not follow the pattern.

Thanks in advance, simak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pattern means: a dot (\\.) followed by 24 symbols. So this matches: ".objective is of the stu".

If you want to detect, say 10 dot symbols, use a pattern like this:
dot_pat="\.{10}"

```
str_detect("The primary.objective is of the study.", "\\.{10}")
str_detect("hello..........world", "\\.{10}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another much poorer approach would be to escape every single "." which Sean indicates is regex for "any character" unless it is escaped.

```
paste(rep("\\.", 10), collapse = "")
## This gives
## [1] "\\.\\.\\.\\.\\.\\.\\.\\.\\.\\."


str_detect("The primary.objective is of the study.", paste(rep("\\.", 10), collapse = ""))
str_detect("hello..........world", paste(rep("\\.", 10), collapse = ""))
```

Comment: This is a poor solution to the original question compared to Karl Forner's solution, but isextremely helpful in terms of helping to explain what's wrong with the OP's original solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern will match a stop (.) followed by 24 of ANY character as the "." means ANY character in regular expressions refer to the help for regex by typing

```
?regex
```

you can detect any number of stops from say 1 to 24 by setting your pattern to something like

```
dot_pat <- "\\.{1,24}"
```

Putting the `\\` in front of the "." will make it match a stop specifically and not just ANY character.